# How to read excel file in Pyspark Data Frame by using Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: python

***Python :*** reading excel file using Pyspark in jupiter notebook. I am using Jupiter Notebook.
I have installed java 'jdk1.8.0_311'. Also I have installed hadoop 'spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2'.
I am able to read only csv file. but there is comming issue in reading EXCEL file. So kindely help anyone.

**Code :** applying this code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()

df_spark = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .option('SheetName','Sheet1') \
        .load('C:/Users/61153825/Desktop/Book1.xlsx')
```

**Error :**

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16068/839898155.py in <module>
----> 1 df_spark = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
      2         .option("header", "true") \
      3         .option('SheetName','Sheet1') \
      4         .load('C:/Users/61153825/Desktop/Book1.xlsx')

~\conda\envs\venv1\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    156         self.options(**options)
    157         if isinstance(path, str):
--> 158             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    159         elif path is not None:
    160             if type(path) != list:

~\conda\envs\venv1\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1307 
   1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
   1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1311 

~\conda\envs\venv1\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\conda\envs\venv1\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o381.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shadeio/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
    at shadeio.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:209)
    at shadeio.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:206)
    at shadeio.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:172)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.$anonfun$openWorkbook$1(WorkbookReader.scala:55)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:251)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.openWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:55)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader.withWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:16)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader.withWorkbook$(WorkbookReader.scala:15)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.withWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:50)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:32)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt(ExcelRelation.scala:32)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.headerColumns$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:104)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.headerColumns(ExcelRelation.scala:103)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.$anonfun$inferSchema$1(ExcelRelation.scala:172)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.inferSchema(ExcelRelation.scala:171)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.<init>(ExcelRelation.scala:36)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:36)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:13)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: shadeio.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 37 more
```

please help.